# Doit-on utiliser « et » ou « ou » dans « 5 ans et moins » ?

Tags: conjonctions, coordination, intervalle

Je viens de voir une publicité où on affiche le prix des billets selon l'âge.

> 5 ans et moins : gratuit

Ne devrait-on pas utiliser *ou* ?

> 5 ans ou moins : gratuit

On a 5 ans ou on a moins dans ce cas. On ne peut pas avoir 5 ans et moins de 5 ans en même temps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

L'un ou l'autre se dit ou se disent ; l'un et l'autre se disent. Le premier est une manière abrégée d'exprimer « gratuit pour les enfants de 5 ans et pour les enfants de moins de 5 ans ». Le deuxième est une manière abrégée d'exprimer « gratuit pour les enfants qui ont 5 ans ou qui ont moins de 5 ans ». Les deux sont grammaticalement et sémantiquement corrects. Les deux sont acceptés par l'usage, mais l'emploi de « et » est plus fréquent dans cette expression (mais « ou » se répand).

[image: ans et moins,ans ou moins,ans et plus,ans ou plus]